# Handle French character UTF-8 while redirecting on JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, jakarta-ee, utf-8, url-encoding

I have a problem with french character in jSP. I have a servlet which redirects to JSP and I have used UTF-8 encoding in servlet. When it redirect to JSP, I can see those french character(request parameter) in URl and in browser I can see those UTF-8 character of an URl in development mode but in JSP, it got screwed. I have tried almost all possiblities like
1)Changed in connector of Tomcat7
2)Used filter

But I could not find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when I submit forms using GET method with UTF-8 encoded data, these steps work, not sure if it helps.

1.At the top of your JSP pages, add this line:

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

2.Change URIEncoding in your Tomcat connector to UTF8 (what I supposed you already did).

```
<Connector URIEncoding="UTF-8" ... >
```

Comment: First answer comes into effect when you do a post request and second one for GET but I dont know why it ain't working in my case.

Comment: Yes, it's weird. Could you elaborate a little more what you did with the servlets and jsps?

Comment: on servlet i have a string which has request parameter then i encode this string in utf-8 using url encoder and concatenate this string to path and redirect to this path from servlet. I can see those french character with ascent in my browser URL  but in JSP it got screwed.

Answer (score 0):

Try response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8") in your servlet before sending response. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: I have tried this too but unfortunately it didn't work as well